# Appending axis to a D3 chart

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm working through a book on data visualization with D3. I'm sorta new to this and I am trying to add axis to my chart. The example code works but for some reason when  I try to append an axis class to my SVG element, it won't work.

My code is below:

```
    function draw(data) {
    //code
    "use strict";

var margin = 50,
    width = 700,
    height = 300;
    var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.collision_with_injury});
    var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.dist_between_fail});

var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([margin, width-margin])
    .domain(x_extent);

var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height-margin, margin])
    .domain(y_extent);

var x_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale("x_scale");
var y_axis = d3.svg.axis().scale("y_scale").orient("left");

    d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){return x_scale(d.collision_with_injury)})
    .attr("cy", function(d){return y_scale(d.dist_between_fail)})
    .attr("r", 5)

    d3.select("svg") 
          .append("g") 
            .attr("class", "x axis") 
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height-margin) + ")") 
          .call(x_axis);

    d3.select("svg")
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin +", 0)")
        .call(y_axis)

     d3.select('.y axis')
     .append('text')
     .text('mean distance between failure (miles)')
     .attr('transform', "rotate (-90, -43, 0) translate(-280)")

    d3.select('.x axis')
    .append('text')
    .text('collisions with injury (per million miles)')
    .attr('x', function(){return (width / 2) - margin})
    .attr('y', margin/1.5) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names cannot contain spaces. When you run the code `.attr("class", "x axis")` you're actually assigning the two classes `x` and `axis` to the element. This is not a problem as such, but the selector `.y axis` doesn't work as you would expect for the same reason. It tries to find an element with class `y` and an `axis` tag (as you didn't put a dot in front of it). This fails, as there is no such element.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to simply assign a one-word class, e.g. `xAxis`. Alternatively, you could change your selector to `.y .axis` to match elements that have those two classes.

Comment: Hi Lars
I changed my code to match what you suggested and I still don't see the axes. The .x.axis gets appended onto the SVG but without any of the values to fill it out and the .y.axis doesn't get appended. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the scales. Did you verify that all data is read correctly and that the ranges of the scales are calculated correctly?

Comment: I need to look into that, I suspect it's also got to do with the data and the code which might not be reading the data well. Thanks Lars.